# Add a html button to each row dynamically in angular material table

Tags: html, angular, dynamic, datatable, sanitization

I have done a code to generate a datatable based on dynamic rows and columns. I need to add a html button in the last column of each row for edit. How to do that. Below is the code

```
<div class="example-table-container" >
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="example-table"
             matSort matSortActive="created" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="desc">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of this.columnHeading | keyvalue; let colIndex = index" matColumnDef="{{disCol.key}}">
          
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef><b>{{disCol.value}}</b></th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element[disCol.key]}}</td>
        </ng-container>
  
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

When i insert html code in value the button is not appearing but only html code is appearing like this

```
<button>Edit</button>
```

I have tried the bypassSecurityTrustHtml also. It gives the error safeValue must use [property]=binding:

Comment: how are you "<button>Edit</button>" adding this in your template?

Answer (score 0):

Angular material table provides a *stickyend* property with some css.
Normally we add an extra **th** with stickyend to solve that.

Below is an example of that..

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="star" stickyEnd>
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
<mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</td>
</ng-container>
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/nneoarrlekb?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.html

Comment: But i am displaying the rows from a dynamic dataset. In the example above all the columns are statically defined. I can't do like that. Any other options please

Comment: So in that *this.columnHeading* push one more dispCol to add the column using ts. And in template make it sticky using condition

Comment: I have added action column in this.columnHeading in component.ts.But i dont know how to make change in the template.

Comment: using   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  
[ngClass]="{'stickyEnd': colIndex +1 === columnHeading.length}"><b>{{disCol.value}}</b></th>

Comment: I have added this part of code inside ng-container but it is not working

Comment: I have done this by push one item to datasource and check that data while the iteration of th and td.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="example-table"
             matSort matSortActive="created" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="desc">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of this.columnHeading | keyvalue; let colIndex = index" matColumnDef="{{disCol.key}}">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef ><b >{{disCol.value}}</b></th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [innerHtml]="element[disCol.key]"></td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
        </tr>
      </table>
```

I have done this using the innerhtml

Answer (score 0):

try to add this

```
   <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="onEdit(row)"><mat-icon>launch</mat-icon></button>
    <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="onDelete(row.$key)"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

do not forget to add this column in displayedColumns

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['fullName', 'email', 'mobile', 'city', 'departmentName', 'actions'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar predicament to you and this is what I came up with.

Firstly, trying to add the html button tag as a value is not a solution and akin to html injection.

Given an example set of columns,

```
const columnHeadings = ['position', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'actions'];
const displayNames = ['No.', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Actions'];
```

we may dynamically populate our table. What I have done here is presented different content for my one column, 'actions', based on a condition that is triggered by the desired column.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="example-table">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{disCol}}" *ngFor="let disCol of columnHeadings; index as i">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{displayNames[i]}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <div *ngIf="column!=='actions'"> {{element[disCol]}} </div>
      <div *ngIf="column==='actions'">
        <button mat-icon-button>
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnHeadings"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnHeadings;" class="element-row"></tr>
</table>
```

By no means have a done a very elegant way to execute this but it is one that works; even if it is somewhat of a  "hack" solution.